# Styles not being applied in angular component

Tags: html, css, angular6

Good afternoon everyone. I'm having a problem in an angular 6 components with the `overflow: hidden` style. I'll give you an example: I have the following html code in my-component component:

```
<div class="slider">
   <div class="slider-tab">Content 1...</div>
   <div class="slider-tab">Content 2...</div>
</div>
```

And the following css:

```
my-component {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

The overflow hidden helps me hide the tabs that are not selected, or not being viewed. But, for some reason, it's not working. It's like the property is not being applied or something because I tested it in another plain html file and worked without problems.
Hope you can help me, and pardon for the ignorance.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: what is 'my-component'? Please provide some context or some additional code

Comment: I'm trying to make an slider. There's actually nothing else than my-component (which is a component in the root app component)

Comment: can you create a plunkr or post more code of the component?

Comment: Sorry for being late, I had been a little bit busy at work. Anyway, I think I found the solution. in the `my-component.component.css` inside my component folder, I just wrote :host {display: block}. It seems that angular selectors have no default display. That made it work